# wix XmlConfig: is it possible to insert a new node in a particular position within a parent node

Tags: xml, xpath, wix

What I'm researching is whether the util:XmlConfig (or anything in the wix tool chest) can be used in such a way as to allow me to create on install a node at a particular position within its parent node.  Here's an example:

```
...
<parentNode parentAttr1="parent attr1 value">
    <childNode childAttr1="child1 attr1 value" />
    <childNode childAttr1="child2 attr1 value" />
</parentNode>
...
```

I'd like to insert a new node between the two children, so that the result would be like this:

```
...
<parentNode parentAttr1="parent attr1 value">
    <childNode childAttr1="child1 attr1 value" />
    <childNode childAttr1="child3 attr1 value" />
    <childNode childAttr1="child2 attr1 value" />
</parentNode>
...
```

The code I have so far will place the new node as the last child of the parentNode and looks like this:

```
...
<util:XmlConfig
    Id="MY_ID"
    File="[PROPERTY_SQLRSPATH]ReportServer\rssrvpolicy.config"
    Action="create"
    On="install"
    ElementPath="//parentNode"
    Node="document"
    Sequence="1">
    <![CDATA[
        <childNode childAttr1="child3 attr1 value" />
]]>
</util:XmlConfig>
...
```

So, there it is in a nutshell.  Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Another wrinkle on this topic would be given this structure:

```
...
<parentNode parentAttr1="parent attr1 value">
    <Abc anAttr="a value" />
    <Def someAttr="some value" />
</parentNode>
...
```

Is there any way to insert another sibling element between the current child elements so that the final structure looks like this??

```
...
<parentNode parentAttr1="parent attr1 value">
    <Abc anAttr="a value" />
    <Ghi YaAttr="yet another value" />
    <Def someAttr="some value" />
</parentNode>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found no way to do this through wix tools.  I've had to add a custom action that places the elements where I want them, and then have the installer add the details I want.  Not what I'd consider great, but works for now, and uninstall works with this as well, though it leaves the empty elements in place.